# C++ Cannot instantiate abstract class error

Tags: c++

I'm a returning college student and my code is really rusty since its been years. We have a program where he gave us a UML template. Anyways im getting a c2259 error, cannot instantiate abstract classes, when I compile and I cannot find the issue. Any ideas?

```
#ifndef OLISTTYPE_H
#define OLISTTYPE_H

#include "ListType.h"

template <class T>
class OListType: public ListType<T> {
 public:

 bool insert(const T&);
void insertFirst(const T&);
void insertLast(const T&);
bool find(const T&) const;

};


template <class T>
 bool OListType<T>::find(const T& item) const {
NodeType<T>* temp = this->head;
while (temp != NULL && temp->info < item) {
    temp = temp->link;
}
return(temp != NULL && temp->info == item);
 }


template <class T>
bool OListType<T>::insert(const T& newItem) {
NodeType<T> *current;
NodeType<T> *trailCurrent;
NodeType<T> *newNode;

bool found;

newNode = new NodeType<T>;
newNode->info = newItem;
newNode->link = nullptr;

if (first == nullptr) {
    first = newNode;
    last = newNode;
    count++;
}
else {
    current = first;
    found = false;
    while (current != nullptr && !found)
        if (current->info >= newItem)
            found = true;
        else {
            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->link;
        }

        if (current == first) {
            newNode->link = first;
            first = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;
            if (current == nullptr)
                last = newNode;
            count++;
        }
}
}
template<class T>
void OListType<T>::insertFirst(const T& newItem) {
insert(newItem);
}
template<class T>
void OListType<T>::insertLast(const T& newItem) {
insert(newItem);
}
#endif
```

ListType.h

---

```
#ifndef LISTTYPE__H
#define LISTTYPE__H

#include <cstddef>
#include "Nodetype.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>

class ListType {

 public:
ListType();
ListType(const ListType<T>&);
virtual ~ListType();
bool operator=(const ListType<T>& right) const;
virtual bool insert(const T&) = 0;
virtual bool eraseAll();
virtual bool erase(const T&) = 0;
bool find(const T&) const;
size_t size() const;
bool empty() const;
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const ListType&);

 protected:
int count;
NodeType<T> *first;
NodeType<T> *last; 
private:
void destroy();
void copy(const ListType<T>&);


};

 template <class T>
 ListType<T>::ListType()
{
first = nullptr;
last = nullptr;
count = 0;
 }

 template <class T>
 ListType<T>::ListType(const ListType<T>& otherList) {
first = nullptr;
copyList(otherList);
 }

 template <class T>
  ListType<T>::~ListType() {
destroy();
  }

 template<class T>
 bool ListType<T>::operator=(const ListType<T>& right) const  
 {
return (current = right.current);
 } 



 template <class T>
bool ListType<T>::eraseAll() {
head = 0;
return true;
}
 template <class T>
 bool ListType<T>::erase(const T& it) {
if (head == 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    struct NodeType<T> *u = head->next, *p = head;
    if (head->item == it)
    {
        head = head->next;
        return true;
    }
    while (u != 0 && u->next != 0)
    {
        if (u->item == it)
        {
            p->next = u->next;
            return true;
        }
        u = u->next;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (u->next == 0 && u->item == it)
    {
        p->next = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
 template <class T>
 bool ListType<T>::find(const T& it) const {
 if (head == 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    struct NodeType<T> *p = head;
    while (p->next != 0)
    {
        if (p->item == it)
        {
            return true;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return false;
  }
  }

template <class T>
size_t ListType<T>::size() const {
return count;
}

template <class T> 
bool ListType<T>::empty() const
 {
   return (first == nullptr);
 }



 template <class T>
void ListType<T>::destroy() {
NodeType<T> *temp;
while (first != nullptr)
{
    temp = first;
    first = first->link;
    delete temp;
}

last = nullptr;
count = 0;
} 



 template <class T>
void ListType<T>::copy(const ListType<T>& otherList) {
nodeType<Type> *newNode;
nodeType<Type> *current;

if (first != nullptr)
    destroylist();
if (otherList.first = nullptr)
{
    first = nullptr;
    last = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}
else {
    current = otherList.first;
    count = otherList.count;
    first = new NodeType<T>;
    first->info = current->info;
    first->link = nullptr
    last = first;
    current = current->link;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        newNode = new NodeType<Type>;
        newNode->info = current->info;
        newNode->link = nullptr;
        last->link = newNode; 
        last = newNode;
        current = current->link; 
    }
}
 }

template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const ListType<T> &list) {
if (list.head) {
    NodeType<T> *temp = list.head;
    out << list.head->item;
    temp = temp->next;
    while (temp != 0) {
        out << "," << temp->item;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
return out;
}
#endif
```

Comment: `OListType` fails to override the `erase()` pure virtual function, as such this template also ends up declaring an abstract class which, as you know, cannot be instantiated. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Surely whitespace and formatting was present in your original college days :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler gives this error, it means that you didn't implement all pure virtual methods of the base class (those with "= 0" after the declaration) in your derived class.

This means that your derived class is still abstract so it can't be instantiated.

There are only two pure virtual methods in the base class, you are missing the erase() method.

Comment: It's more common to say *"pure virtual"* than *"abstract virtual"*.

Comment: thx, corrected...